# What is the best practice in passing responses from server calls to the component that invoked it?

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing a functionality where users can open a panel in the app which submits some data to the server. And server returns whether the data is valid or not, which should then be forwarded to the component. Currently, I do this side effect in action creator and update my Redux store to reflect the response from the server (valid or invalid, basically)

I want the panel to auto close if the data is valid. But the issue is that Redux store could already have ‘valid’ as the API status for a previous call (which was never erased), so there is no way to tell whether this valid status is from previous submission or current submission.

Currently, I am just dispatching an event which set the validness to pending before the each submission call to the server. And in the panel component, if `this.props.validness === 'pending' && nextProps.validness===true`, I close the panel. But I fear that it is not exactly best practice to have the View depend on not just the current state, but also the previous one.

Comment: Your strategy is right. That is how I will do. The other option is while closing the panel, reset the state of the reducer to its initial state.

Answer (score 0):

There is one suggestion I have. To have another state in the reducer - loading. Set loading to true when the API call is made. And when API call finishes, set loading to false. The validness property can be set to undefined when the API call is made.

Comment: I ended up bypassing my redux store. I am simply having the response from the API call returned in `redux-thunk` and deal with the response in my component (since all my other components don't care about its response). So no subsequent `dispatch` is called in the action creator.